# How do I apply factor scores (Exp) to observations in my data? How do I match observations in my dataset to a value based on vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, statistics, analytics, data-manipulation

I have seen similar questions asked here before but I have never found a satisfactory answer.

I am analyzing my data using item response theory package called ltm.
My data (binary answers to 25 test questions for many subjects) look like this:

```
q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15 q16 q17 q18 q19 q20 q21 q22 q23 q24
0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1
1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0
0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

Next I start my analysis

```
library(ltm)
model <- ltm(questionsPretest ~ z1, IRT.param = na.action = NULL)
```

To assess the ability of each test taker I run factor scores:

```
 scores <- factor.scores(model)
```

This gives me ability of a student given a vector of her answers (24 1s and 0s).
Ability (called z1) is stored like this in scores:

```
str(scores)
List of 6
 $ score.dat:'data.frame':  3088 obs. of  28 variables:
  ..$ q1   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q2   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q3   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q4   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q5   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q6   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q7   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q8   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q9   : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q10  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q11  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q12  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q13  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q14  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ q15  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
  ..$ q16  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ q17  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ q18  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q19  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q20  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q21  : num [1:3088] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ q22  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q23  : num [1:3088] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ q24  : num [1:3088] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ Obs  : num [1:3088] 87 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Exp  : num [1:3088] 5.553 2.275 0.213 0.096 0.061 ...
  ..$ z1   : num [1:3088] -1.9 -1.87 -1.61 -1.55 -1.53 ...
  ..$ se.z1: num [1:3088] 0.573 0.583 0.535 0.523 0.524 ...
 $ method   : chr "EB"
 $ B        : num 5
 $ call     : language tpm(data = questionsPretest, type = "latent.trait",             IRT.param = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
 $ resp.pats: logi FALSE
 $ coef     : num [1:24, 1:3] 0.000017879 0.311805093 0.000045896 0.000000182 0.000004738 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:24] "q1" "q2" "q3" "q4" ...
  .. ..$ : Named chr [1:3] "Gussng" "Dffclt" "Dscrmn"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Guessing" "Difficulty" "Discrimination"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "fscores"
```

What I need to do is assign z1 to observations in my dataset based on answers. Looking at the output of scores, I would assign z1 = -1.9 to all people whom answered 0 to all of the questions. I would assign z1 = -1.87 to all people whom answered 0 to all questions except question q21.

As you can tell, there are 3088 observed permutations of answers in my dataset, so I would really like to avoid doing this by hand :)

Could anybody please suggest how to do it in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your output it shows that `scores$score.dat` is a data.frame with 28 rows and 3088 columns. Each column represents a test subject, I presume. The 27th row `$z1` is the score you want to assign to each subject, so, without trying to be rude, don't you kind of already have what you need? If this is not what you are after, let me know and I can try to assist further.

Comment: @BryanGoggin - thanks for the reply. My dataset has 3459 observations. scores$score.dat contains 3088 observed permutations of answers in my dataset.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see where you're coming from now. If I come up with anything I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have data.frame df with a variable named obsScores that marks the score for each participant (observation).

Here are two assignment mechanisms:

brute force, just give the raw value to each participant:

```
df$factorScore <- scores$z1[df$obsScores]
```

No need to worry about the difference in sizes. R will be happy to reuse values.

The second method, you could use a factor variable

```
df$factorScore <- factor(df$obsScores, levels=1:length(scores$z1), labels=scores$z1)
```

The first one is preferable for analysis.